# Removing borders in libreoffice writer

Tags: libreoffice

I created a LibreOffice Writer document, and copied some text from a web page.

Now whenever I create a bulleted list, the items have a top and bottom black border.

I can remove the border using Format - Paragraph - Borders - none, but then the border just jumps to the next or previous item.

How can I get rid of this strange phenomenon, without writing the entire text in a new document?

Comment: Press F5 to open "navigator". Select the OLE Object and delete it.

Answer (score 40):

I know this thread is already dead but if someone does stumble upon this thread while trying to solve this problem, here's my suggestion:

Go to View and from there uncheck "Text borders".

Comment: In Libreoffice 5.4.1.2 is View > Text Boundaries and View > Table Boundaries.

Comment: Works fine in  LibreOffice Writer 5.1.6.2

Comment: @Katu, How about LibreOffice 6.0.73

Comment: Works in LibreOffice 7.2

Answer (score 7):

None of the above worked for me.

What did work was to go to **Tools - Options**, then click on the "**+**" beside "**LibreOffice**" - go down to "**Appearance**" and click on it.

At the top of the white box on the right, uncheck "**text boundaries**" - then click on "**okay**."

Comment: Seems the latest version no longer has an `Appearance` section :/

Answer (score 3):

This instruction is for LibreOffice 5.1.5.2 (tested on Fedora 24):

To remove border of pages in a document (most likely created in Microsoft word software), on the main menu go to Format->Page, then to Borders tab. You'll see the following screen:
[image]

There are four squares on the top left of the dialog under *Default*. Select the leftmost one as shown in the picture, and then press OK, all borders will be gone.

Answer (score 2):

try to use Format-Page-Borders then select none. instead of paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

Select several paragraphs including the one that has the annoying border. Add bottom border to all. Apply. Reopen the borders dialog. Click on the remove all icon and apply. You´re done :D (I hope. Worked for me)

Answer (score 2):

Mark the section in question, add a white border (or whatever background color you may use) on the left only, apply. Removed all other borders for me.